# DataType Attribute Decoration through Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Supose this Scenario

```
public class CustomerMetaData
{


    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]       
    public String EmailAddress {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]       
    public String UrlUser {get;set;}

}
```

I need to get via **reflection** DataType of all properties on this class, but extensive web search, i not found any solution around this type of DataAttribute.

I explain a bit more, i dont need to know the datatype of the property Like, String, Boolean....) i need the part of the [DataType(DataType.....)] Attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Some Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the GetCustomAttributes method.

This is from memory, but it would go something like this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(CustomerMetaData).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo p in props)
{
    object[] attribs = p.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    // do something with the attributes
}
```

Look up the GetProperties and GetCustomAttributes methods to make sure of the parameters: if any of your properties are non-public, you'll have to specify some additional information to get information for them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!
After some fixes i got the attribute inside "attribs" array.

Comment: Added the complete solution for my question, because this im glad to share with everyone

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it for 5 years...

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(CustomerMetaData).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo p in props)
{
    IEnumerable<DataTypeAttibute> dataTypeAttrs = p.GetCustomAttributes<DataTypeAttribute>(false);
    foreach(var attr in dataTypeAttrs)
    {
        DataType dataType = attr.DataType;
        // do something with the datatype
    }
}
```